# SOAP error application/soap+msbin1

Tags: php, soap

Does anyone knew how to correct or is there a solution for this error?>

```
HTTP/1.1 415 Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="urn:HealthCareServiceWCF/GetClaimsList"' was not the expected type 'application/soap+msbin1'. Cache-Control: private Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5 Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=ilvagsgvofc2r5jclkvjtysv; path=/; HttpOnly X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date: Fri, 27 Jun 2014 22:26:03 GMT Content-Length: 0
```

Here's My Code.

```
<?php //-->
```

class LocalSoapClient extends SoapClient {
  protected $_xml = null;

```
public function __construct($wsdl, $options, $xml) 
{
  $this->_xml = $xml;
  parent::__construct($wsdl, $options);
}

public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0)  
{
  ob_start();
  $request = $this->_xml;
  return parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way);
  ob_end_clean();
}

}

function mcrypts_encrypt($encrypted)
 {
 //Padding 6/25/2014
 $pad       = 16 - (strlen($encrypted) % 16);
 $encrypted = $encrypted . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
//Encrypt//Decode
$iv        = base64_decode('...');
 $key       = base64_decode('...');
 $plaintext = mcrypt_encrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $encrypted, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv );
 //Return encrypted Data
 return base64_encode($plaintext);
 }

 $portal    = 'CaregiverPortalService';
 $userName  = '...';
 $password  = '...';
 $passwordnew  = '...';
 $url       =     "https://webapp.healthcaresynergy.com:8002/demoalpha/HealthCareServiceWCF.svc?singleWsdl";  
 $option    = array('trace' => 1 ); 

 $xml       = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">'.
             '<soap:Header/>'.
             '<soap:Body>'.
                '<Login>'.
                   '<userName>'.$userName.'</userName>'.
                   '<password>'.$password.'</password>'.
                   '<newPassword>'.$passwordnew.'</newPassword>'.
                '</Login>'.
             '</soap:Body>'.
          '</soap:Envelope>';

 $client = new LocalSoapClient($url, $option, $xml);

  try 
 { 
   $client->Login();
   $response = $client->__getLastResponse(); 
   echo 'result';
   echo "<br/>";
   echo htmlspecialchars($response);
   $p        = xml_parser_create();
         xml_parse_into_struct($p, $response, $vals, $index);
          xml_parser_free($p);
          echo "Index array\n";
          echo('<pre>');
          print_r($index);
          echo('<pre/>');
          echo "\nVals array\n";
          //print_r($vals);
          //echo $vals[114]['value'];
   //$sessiontoken = $vals[114]['value'];

 }
   catch (SoapFault $fault)
 {
   echo    $client->__getLastRequestHeaders();
   echo   'Request : <br/><xmp>', 
        $client->__getLastRequest(), 
        '</xmp><br/><br/> Error Message : <br/>', 
        $fault->getMessage(); 
    echo   '<pre>';
    print_r ($client);
 }
```

Thank you for everyone who will give their answer, help, suggestion or point of view.

Comment: From server or client perspective? Post your code, looking at the error it seems the client and server want/use different content types.

Comment: @MattTheNinja  - Post Updated as requested. Thanks.

Comment: Always pointing in this line `return parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way);`this is where the error always shows

Comment: someone found the solution I have the same problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely that `ob_end_clean();` is causing trouble. From what I can see in your code, you don't even need it at all.

Just do it like this:

```
public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0) {
  $request = $this->_xml;
  return parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way);
}
```

If you actually do need it, at least use `ob_end_clean` before the `return` otherwise it has no effect :P